# Android getting the spinner id and name placed in the spinner

Tags: android, spinner

thank u for your time.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the **id** and **name** from a sql and place them both in the spinner.
with out creating a new **AsyncTask** and **doInBackGround** ect..
Witch will be active then **onItemselected**.
I have to little experience to make this decission.

With the **JSON** i have now working it only allows the **ID** or the **NAME**.
So i need to know if it is better to modify this **JSON** or create a new **JSON** with new **php** actions.
If i can get the confirmation to do this in the first this will save me time.
I am already 5 days at this problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i got it

```
private void loadSpinner(){
 for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
                lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName() + categoriesList.get(i).getId());

            }
    }
```